# How to error handle duplicate student ID in array

Tags: java, arrays, object, duplicates

Please help me understand how I can prevent inserting a student if there's a duplicate ID. I am trying to understand how without importing anything though I don't mind you sharing anything you got so I can learn. Thanks

> I tried looping over every object and checking studentArray.getID() if it matches, but I can't seem to get the output right. I also tried storing every ID into another array and comparing both arrays though I think I have to use nested for loop and it broke all my code. I also couldn't get to figure out how I can just set ID to 1, then add 1 to a max of 10 since studentArray[10] is 10. So this code is the cleanest I could provide.

```
int size = studentArray.length;
System.out.print("Insert Student ID: ");
int ID = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Insert Student Name: ");
String name = sc.next();
System.out.print("Insert Student Age: ");
int age = sc.nextInt();
Student student1 = new Student(name,age,ID);
studentArray[size] = student1;
size++;
System.out.print("\nStudent Inserted!\n");
```

Comment: why don't you use `Set` to avoid duplicate element?

Comment: Not sure I understand

Comment: Please refer to _javadoc_ for interface [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Comment: "the type Student is not generic. it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>" and I am not supposed to use any collections

Comment: If you don't want to use any collections, check before inserting any Student Object to your list, if it's already there do the needful.

Comment: Dude I love you I got it to work now!! @AshutoshSharma

Answer (score 0):

Now since you're not supposed to use collections what you can do is to iterate over your *studentArray* to check if the current ID is already present in the array. If it's not present do the insertion else skip it.
The following code snippet can help:

```
 int size = studentArray.length;
 System.out.print("Insert Student ID: ");
 int ID = sc.nextInt();
 System.out.print("Insert Student Name: ");
 String name = sc.next();
 System.out.print("Insert Student Age: ");
 int age = sc.nextInt();
 int i=0
 for(;i<size;i++){
 if(studentArray[i].ID==ID)
   break;
    }
 if(i==size){
 Student student1 = new Student(name,age,ID);    
 studentArray[size] = student1;
 size++;
 System.out.print("\nStudent Inserted!\n");
  }
 else{
  System.out.print("\nStudent with the given ID is already present in the array!\n");
  }
```